# Beaver builder other libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, builder, beaver

I searched the web all over the place and withing Beaver builder itself but could not found what I wanted.

I want to use some jQuery libraries for my animations. How do I add other libraries into my project, so I can use those elements within my projects?

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://docs.wpbeaverbuilder.com/beaver-builder/styles/code/custom-javascript/)

To add custom JavaScript to a specific page :

- Click the title bar in the upper left corner to open the Tools menu, then click Layout CSS & JavaScript.
- On the JavaScript tab, enter your JavaScript code.
- Click Save.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to enqueue scripts (including adding libraries) is to use:

`wp_enqueue_script($handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer);`

Where $deps is an array which takes the name of any libraries you're using e.g.

`$deps = array('jquery');`

[Read more](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)

If you haven't had much experience with PHP, you could add some html and just use a script tag to include the library you want, although this is not convention. E.g.

`<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js'></script>`